# Determining poles and zeros from those of interconnected two-port networks

Tags: passive-networks, pole-zeroplot, parameters, resistor-ladder, 2-port-network

My goal is to find the poles and zeros of a large network. Specifically a cascade connection of series C's and shunt L's. One could also consider this a CL Ladder circuit. I am interested in characterizing the poles and zeros of these ladders as a function of the number of nodes.

[image: CL ladder circuit]

While specific insight into these ladders is of course appreciated, **my question** is broader: can anything general be said about the poles and zeros of a network in terms of the poles and zeros of the constituent two ports?

More specifically, if I have two cascaded two ports (see below), and I know the poles and zeros of each constituent two-port network, does this information give me any particular insight into the values of the poles and zeros of the overall network?

[image]

I have tried generating the impedance functions by finding the ABCD parameters of the overall network, then transforming to z parameters. This gives me functions which I can then determine the poles and zeros of analytically. This is an effective strategy, but this method does not scale well. I'd like to look at VERY "long" ladders.

Any guidance is appreciated.

Comment: Are the Ls and Cs the same value. If not then difficult and not scaling very well at all. Iterative matrix multiplication on real values (not algebraic values) seems appropriate. Maybe you can explain why this is an EE problem.

Comment: @Andyaka I'm interested in two cases: One where the L's and C's are the same value, and another when the L's are all the same but the C's alternate between C1 and C2.

Answer (score 0):

> *@Andyaka I'm interested in two cases: One where the L's and C's are
> the same value, and another when the L's are all the same but the C's
> alternate between C1 and C2*

For the case when L and C are the same for all stages I think this transmission line derivation for characteristic impedance may provide some pointers. The thing is this; when the Ls and Cs are equal value (even though their positions have swapped), the output impedance of one stage tends can be the input impedance of the next stage. You can imagine that if your actual lumped circuit was symmetrical (by doubling up on input and output capacitances), then the same sort of math is involved.

Here is the standard transmission line solution for references and maybe you can use this method for your lumped sections joined together

So, consider a "lump" of transmission line connected to the continuation of that transmission line (\$Z_0\$): -

[image]

- R is series resistance of cable for a given length
- L is series inductance of cable for a given length
- G is parallel conductance of cable for a given length
- C is parallel capacitance of cable for a given length
- \$Z_0\$ to the right is the continuation of the cable

Therefore the impedance looking into the left is: -

$$Z_0 = R + j\omega L + Z_0||\dfrac{1}{G + j\omega C}$$

$$= R + j\omega L + \dfrac{\frac{Z_0}{G+j\omega C}}{Z_0 + \frac{1}{G+j\omega C}}$$

$$= R + j\omega L + \dfrac{Z_0}{1 + Z_0(G+j\omega C)}$$

$$Z_0[1 + Z_0(G+j\omega C)] = [R+j\omega L][1 + Z_0(G+j\omega C)]+Z_0$$

$$Z_0 + Z_0^2(G+j\omega C) = R+j\omega L + Z_0[(R+j\omega L)(G+j\omega C)]+Z_0$$

$$Z_0^2(G+j\omega C) = R+j\omega L + Z_0[(R+j\omega L)(G+j\omega C)]$$

The important thing next is to recognize that \$(R+j\omega L)(G+j\omega C)\$ is insignificant as the "lump" approaches zero length and we are left with: -

$$Z_0^2(G+j\omega C) = R+j\omega L$$

hence $$Z_0 = \sqrt{\dfrac{R+j\omega L}{G+j\omega C}}$$

Answer (score 0):

Your question pertains to a particular network, but a general approach to answering the question applies to all networks.  Middlebrook published an early paper on the subject.

> Middlebrook, R.D., 1989. Null double injection and the extra element
> theorem. IEEE Transactions on Education, 32(3), pp.167-180.

Later he generalized this approach somewhat.

> Middlebrook, R.D., Vorpérian, V. and Lindal, J., 1998. The N extra
> element theorem. IEEE Transactions on Circuits and Systems I:
> Fundamental Theory and Applications, 45(9), pp.919-935.

Vorpérian wrote an entire book addressing the subject.

> Vorpérian, V., 2002. Fast analytical techniques for electrical and
> electronic circuits. Cambridge University Press.

I believe this book by Basso also addresses the technique.

> Basso, C.P., 2016. Linear circuit transfer functions: An introduction
> to fast analytical techniques. John Wiley & Sons.

There's a lot of material in these articles and books, more than can be replicated in a brief StackExchange response, but all of them describe *how* to analyze these networks.  That is different and, I submit, much better than answering the question you have asked:  how to analyze a *particular* network.